# How can I display an image as a tooltip?

Tags: html

I have an HTML page which contains a GIF, as demonstrated in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hckc4/).

The source is:

```
<p class="Output">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ywXKLgY.gif" alt="Untitled-4_1.gif" width="540" height="410" style="vertical-align:middle;" usemap="#map_1" />
    <map name="map_1">
        <area shape="rect" coords="30,132,98,111" title="About Me" href="http://www.wolfram.com" />
    </map>
</p>
```

As you can see, by hovering over the purple area, a tooltip appears that says "About Me", as illustrated in the figure below.

[image]

However, I'd like for that tooltip to be an image rather than the text it is now. Is this possible? And if so, how can I achieve that?

Comment: It's not clear from your link or your question what you're asking.

Comment: @HyperGroups on hover you want to display image.. or tool tip providing the info about link.. :)

Comment: Try to explain a bit more what you actually want ?

Comment: @SurrealDreams how about now

Comment: @MuhammadSaqlainArif how about now

Comment: @AviralSingh How about now

Comment: You want the text "About Me" to be an image instead of text?

Comment: I still don't get it...

Comment: @MrLister Yes, you got me!

Comment: @Zaibis see MrLister's comment

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe there is a way to do this if you are talking about using an image for the default browser tooltip that shows up when hovering over an element with a title attribute.